# Rails 5 - Devise - When I login it always logs me in as the same user regardless of what credentials are used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

Everything was set up fine and seemed to be working. Suddenly I have an issue where if I log out and then log back in again with a different username it just logs me back in always as the first user.

Example:

user one - first@domain.com / password1

user two - second@domain.com / password2

Even if I log out and then log back in again as user two (verified as signed up correctly) it will log me in as user one.

**Here is my user.rb file**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
    # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

    acts_as_voter
    has_many :links
    has_many :comments

    # Virtual attribute for authenticating by either username or email
    # This is in addition to a real persisted field like 'username'
    attr_accessor :login

    def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
      conditions = warden_conditions.dup
      if login = conditions.delete(:login)
        where(conditions.to_h).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
      elsif conditions.has_key?(:username) || conditions.has_key?(:email)
        where(conditions.to_h).first
      end
      conditions[:email].downcase! if conditions[:email]
      where(conditions.to_h).first
    end

    validates :username, presence: :true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
    validates_format_of :username, with: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]*$/, :multiline => true

    validate :validate_username
    def validate_username
      if User.where(email: username).exists?
        errors.add(:username, :invalid)
      end
    end
end
```

**Application Controller**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  protected
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    added_attrs = [:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :sign_up, keys: added_attrs
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :account_update, keys: added_attrs
  end
end
```

Comment: What I've noticed is that it seems to take the password parameter (the password was the same for both).

If I try another user with a different password - it doesn't work at all

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check your controllers. If you're determining the logged in user by using anything other than `current_user`, you may have used the wrong query or perhaps were using a specific user for testing purposes.

Comment: I'm not sure its that. I've checked the controllers and nothing out of place. Weirdly if I sign up it logs me in under the correct user, but if I sign out and back in again it defaults me to user1 no matter what I enter

Answer (score 0):

Check your User model. You're using `:rememberable` and might be passing a session cookie without realizing.